Can you keep the original Excel formatting when exporting the file with R?
I am reading an Excel file, which contains a lot of different cell styles, in R with "import_list". I use some functions to filter the data and then I export the file with "write.xlsx". The updated file does not keep any of the style formatting. Can I export the file keeping the original cell styles?

If you are using the openxlsx package, the workflow loadWorkbook(), writeData(), saveWorkbook() should preserve the formatting.

To add to @AndrewGustar 's comment: if you wish to create a new excel workbook for your output,  I'd say: just duplicate the source workbook and write to that copy.
